# php regex templating + localization improvement

Tags: php, regex

Because I am a pretty newbie in regex, I can't manage the following:
In many frameworks we use functions like __($key) to localize strings. It's not very practical, as we have much to type:

```
<?php echo __('Hello'); ?>.
```

I'd love to use the following syntax: [[ Hello ]].
In the background it should work like:

```
preg_replace('some cool regex', $this->_($key), $view);
```

Though I read numerous tutorials about regex, I am not able to realize this.

Additionally, I would like to provide a set of variables to this function to make i18n strings more flexible. Example:

```
view.phtml: [[ You have n new messages | n=5 ]]
localization.csv: You have n new messages | You have { n ? 0 : 'no new messages' | 1 : '1 new message' | else : n + ' new messages' }.
result: You have 5 new Messages.
```

I am pretty curious how you would do this. I'd be pretty thankful for any tip showing in the right direction.

Comment: You can do this using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback), with this function you can match and "catch" a certain string with regex, and then "process" it directly with PHP. Which will give you more control over replacing strings. The problem is you will have to write pretty "complex" regexes if you want to do it right. I'll give you an example: Say you have `[[ You have n new messages | n=5 ]]`, what if someone use `]]` in his text `[[ You have n [[new]] messages | n=5 ]]`, this will make your "simple" regex like `\[\[.*?\]\]` fail.

Comment: Since it will match `[[ You have n [[new]]` and not `[[ You have n [[new]] messages | n=5 ]]`. So you would need a regex that can handle nested brackets, which is possible with PCRE. But as you stated, you're a newbie in the domain. I highly suggest to use an already made templating engine. Otherwise, you'll be searching forever to fix "small" exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you can do is to use the preg_replace_callback function to deal with each match:

```
$that = $this;
$view = preg_replace_callback('~\[\[\K(?>[^]]++|](?!]))*~', function ($m) use ($that) {
    return $that->__($m); }, $view);
```

I have used a closure, but you can write your own named function and use it with [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: @BarthZalewski: Because before php 5.4 you can't have access to $this in a closure, if your php version is >=5.4, you can remove it and replace all $that by $this. See "this" post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599721/php-5-4-closures

Comment: Ok understand. It works ALMOST. This replaces the text but not the brackets. So it becomes "[[ Ja ]]" instead of "Ja", when I write [[ Yes ]].

Comment: I tried to str_replace this here and there but it doesn't work.